# Creating raster attribute table for future analysis

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro

A raster was given to me in order to perform antabulate by area process. However, the raster does not have an attribute table. It is not single band, so I cannot perform the build raster attribute table tool, and I need the values to be in floating format, not integer.

Is there a way to create a table that lists each cell's value?

Answer (score 1):

Only integer rasters can have an attribute table, so unless you convert it to an integer you will not have an attribute table to use.

A trick is to convert it into integer by multiply it up by an appropriate value. For example your current float raster has numbers that are to 3 decimal places (e.g. 123.444). By multiplying this by 1000 you move the decimal point (e.g. 123444). Then pass that raster through the INT() tool to actually convert it to an integer raster, finally build a raster attribute table. You then work with your raster in that format, do your processing and then simply divide any values by 1000 to get back to the original cell values.

Comment: Except it's not completely that simple, because if the old value was 123.4449, you'd get back 123.4440. Be sure you know where to round and where to truncate.